react-native-maps showing blank screen on some android devices
Since last few weeks, we are noticing blank screen while rendering map in some android devices, there is no logs, and no app crashes, just blank screen with Google logo on bottom left corner.
It's happening in both dev and prod apps that are using different keys. App is in store since last one year, and was working perfectly fine.
However, it's working fine in iOS devices, and even in my android Emulator.
Android API version details
minSdkVersion = 23 compileSdkVersion = 33 targetSdkVersion = 33
react-native-maps = ^1.7.1, react-native = 0.71.14

I tried following approaches but none of them worked

using a new API key without any restriction
updating react-native-maps library to 1.13.2
specifying playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1" in build.gradle and adding it's dependency on app/build.gradle

